# How do I compute the improper integral $\int_0^{1/e}\frac{dx}{x(\log x)^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

The given integral is $\int_0^{1/e}\frac{dx}{x(\log x)^{2}}$

**ATTEMPT**

I see that problem is at $0$, so I write the integral as

$$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\int_{0+t}^{1/e}\frac{dx}{x(\log x)^{2}}$$

Now I use the substitution, $\log(x)=u$. So now my integral becomes

$$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\int_{\log(t)}^{-1}\frac{du}{u^{2}}$$

Evaluating this gives me the answer $1$, but the textbook states that the answer us $8/3$. I would like to know where I went wrong

Thanks

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct ! One more typo in a text book, I guess.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wolfram Alpha confirms that you are right.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=integrate%20from%200%20to%201%2Fe%20of%201%2F(x*log(x)%5E2)) Your book probably has a misprint.